# Firefox creates additionally rect covering vertex while using insertVertex to create SVG as a child

Tags: javascript, svg, mxgraph

I'm using the mxGraph (javascript) library to create diagrams.
I'm trying to insert as a child a CSV vertex to the existing parent vertex.
I add the `pointer-events: none;` to the newly created vertex to allow the covered shape to move.
Everything works fine on Chrome or Safari, the image is added, but on Firefox is created additional `<rect>` which covers `<image>` with `pointer-events: none;` and it doesn't have the `pointer-events: none;` attribute but `pointer-events: fill;`, as a result, cannot move the parent shape.

Has anyone any idea what is happening here and how to avoid this situation?
Bellow steps I've done.

```
//create new svg
const someSvgImage = (color) => (`<svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect x="3" y="3" width="10" height="10" rx="16" stroke="${color}"/>
    </svg>`);

const color = '#9FCBFF';

const testImage = new mxImageBundle();
nodImage.putImage('mySvgImage', 'data:image/svg+xml,' + someSvgImage(color));
this.graph.addImageBundle(testImage);

graph.insertVertex(
        parent,
        null,
        'someValue',
        0,
        0,
        100,
        100,
        'shape=image;fillColor=transparent;pointerEvents=false;image=mySvgImage',
        true
      );
```

The result on Chrome and Firefox:
(On Chrome everything works fine, on Firefox shape is covered and no-movable)

[The result on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awi2y.png)

[The result on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1VJy.png)

I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: you can't use the # character in a data url, you have to URL encode it so I'm surprised this works at all in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: I added encodeURIComponent, but unfortunately - no difference